# Python access dataclass default_factory field without instantiating it

Tags: python, static-methods, python-dataclasses

I have a classmethod `create_instance()` of a dataclass `Bar` that needs to check on a `field(default_factory=...)`-type parameter of the dataclass before returning an instance of the dataclass:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import Dict


@dataclass
class Bar:
    number: int
    static_dict: Dict[str, int] = field(
        default_factory=lambda: {
            'foo': 1,
        }
    )

    @classmethod
    def create_instance(cls) -> 'Bar':
        access = cls.static_dict
        return cls(number=access['foo'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo = Bar.static_dict  # 1) fails already
    foo = Bar.create_instance()  # 2) fails too since it uses 1)
```

This fails with:

`AttributeError: type object 'Bar' has no attribute 'static_dict'`

Without type-hinting the return value, e.g.

```
@classmethod
def create_instance(cls):
    access = cls.static_dict
    return cls(number=access['foo-1'])
```

if fails by mentioning the dataclass itself doesn't have the attribute:

`AttributeError: type object 'Bar' has no attribute 'static_dict'`.

The same error would occur using a staticmethod e.g. with type hinting:

```
@staticmethod
def create_instance_static() -> 'Bar':
    access = Bar.static_dict
    return Bar(number=access['foo'])
```

My very ugly workaround is to define a global variable and pass it into the class, which lets me use the `create_instance()`-method:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import Dict

GLOBAL_DICT = {
    'foo': 2,
}


@dataclass
class BarWorkaround:
    number: int
    static_dict: Dict[str, int] = field(
        default_factory=lambda: GLOBAL_DICT
    )

    @classmethod
    def create_instance(cls) -> 'BarWorkaround':
        access = GLOBAL_DICT
        return cls(number=access['foo'])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo = BarWorkaround.create_instance()  # works as intended
```

Can't say I'm a fan of defining globals for something like this. My guess is something about the way dataclasses are constructed interferes with my accessing the static default attribute, but I don't get what it is.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using a `static` method - for ex. why not use a class method?

Comment: Haven't used classmethods yet, I only looked into them just now - definitely true for readability (doesn't solve the issue though)

Comment: I adjusted the question to use a classmethod as suggested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consider converting the `create_instance` to a class method, and then calling [`dataclasses.fields`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html?highlight=fields#dataclasses.fields), which returns a list of dataclass fields for a provided dataclass. Each element in the fields tuple will be a [`Field`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html?highlight=fields#dataclasses.Field) type.

For example:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, field, fields
from typing import Dict


@dataclass
class Bar:
    number: int
    static_dict: Dict[str, int] = field(
        default_factory=lambda: {
            'foo': 1,
        }
    )

    @classmethod
    def create_instance(cls) -> 'Bar':
        access = next(f for f in fields(Bar)
                      if f.name == 'static_dict').default_factory()

        return Bar(number=access['foo'])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # this should fail (`static_dict` is an instance - not class - attribute)
    # foo = Bar.static_dict

    # this should work though
    static_dict_field = next(f for f in fields(Bar) if f.name == 'static_dict')
    lambda_fn = static_dict_field.default_factory
    print(lambda_fn())  # {'foo': 1}

    foo = Bar.create_instance()  # 2) works with `dataclasses.fields`
```

---

If you plan to call `create_instance` multiple times, for performance reasons it might be a good idea to cache the `default_factory` value, for ex. using a "cached" class property, or a simple workaround like this:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field, fields
from typing import Dict, ClassVar, Callable


@dataclass
class Bar:
    number: int
    static_dict: Dict[str, int] = field(
        default_factory=lambda: {
            'foo': 1,
        }
    )
    # added for type hinting and IDE support
    #
    # note: `dataclasses` ignores anything annotated with `ClassVar`, or else
    # not annotated to begin with.
    __static_dict_factory__: ClassVar[Callable[[], Dict[str, int]]]

    @classmethod
    def create_instance(cls) -> 'Bar':
        return Bar(number=cls.__static_dict_factory__()['foo'])


# need to set it outside, or perhaps consider using a metaclass approach
setattr(Bar, '__static_dict_factory__',
        next(f for f in fields(Bar) if f.name == 'static_dict').default_factory)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo1 = Bar.create_instance()
    foo2 = Bar.create_instance()

    foo1.static_dict['key'] = 123
    print(foo1.static_dict)

    # assert each instance gets its own copy of the dict
    assert foo1.static_dict != foo2.static_dict
```

Comment: Not all heroes wear capes